# Serialize a form and a list

Tags: jquery

I try to keep track of the values of a form and a list. I use jQuery. I can serialize a form but I have problems to do the same with a list. Can someone help to serialize that list?

I have the sample here to check and play: http://jsfiddle.net/rTgL3/

HTML:

```
<form action="">
<input type="text" name="item-1" value="item1" /><br>
<input type="text" name="item-2" value="item2" /><br>
<input type="text" name="item-3" value="item3" /><br>
</form>
<div id="buttonForm">Serialize form</div>

<br><br>

<ul id="list">
  <li id="item_1">Item1</li>
  <li id="item_2">Item2</li>
  <li id="item_3">Item3</li>
</ul>
<div id="buttonList">Serialize list</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$("#buttonForm").click(function(){
    var dataForm = $("form").serialize();
    alert(dataForm);
});

$("#buttonList").click(function(){
    var dataList = $("list").serialize();
    alert(dataList);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuerys `serialize` is just for form elements. As you can read here: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/.

Futhermore your selector `$("list")` isn't quite right. `list` is an identifier, so the selector should look like this: `$("#list")`.

Why don't you serialize the list yourself by iterating through all items and appending them to a string? Like this example (without caring for depth):

```
$("#buttonList").click(function() {
    // empty string to save the result
    var dataList = "";

    // find all li elements within the element with the id list
    var $entries = $("#list").find('li');

    // iterate through all these items, with i as index and item itself as entry
    $entries.each(function(i, entry) { 

        // append the elements id attribute and its content to the string, like: item_1=Item1 for <li id="item_1">Item1</li>
        dataList += $(entry).attr('id') + '=' + $(entry).text();

        // add & to the string, if the entry is not the last one
        if (i != $entries.length-1) {
            dataList += '&';
        }
   });

   // alert the result string
   alert(dataList);
});
```

Comment: It works but I do not understand it. I am just learning and it is too complicated for me. I will try to find information of each part

Comment: @Nrc I added some comments to explain every line. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can ***NOT*** serialize a list *(http://api.jquery.com/serialize)*. Also, in the provided `jsfiddle`, I got the following ***observations***:

- Use `$('#list')` instead of `$('list')` as your `selector` since `list` is the `id` of your element.
- `</ul>` end tag is missing.

---

Try this:

***Live Demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/rTgL3/4/

---

Get all `li` elements inside `#list` by returning the `id=text` of each element stored into an `array`.

```
var array = $('#list li').map(onListMap).get();
var qStr = array.join('&'); // queryString needed
```

***onListMap*** function:

```
function onListMap(idx, el) {
   return el.id + '=' + $(el).text(); // Use '.html()' if needed
};
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to create json object first and use param to serialize it.working code below

```
$("#buttonForm").click(function(){
    var dataForm = $("form").serialize();
    alert(dataForm);
});

var myObject = {};
$("#list li").each(function(){
    var t = $(this).attr('id')
   myObject[t]=$(this).html();
});

$("#buttonList").click(function(){
    alert($.param(myObject));
});
```

update http://jsfiddle.net/rTgL3/4/

Comment: i have used id as key and html as value, you can change it as per your requirement.